# Why does login to a website using HttpPost show me the login page again?

Tags: android, http-post

I am developing an Android app, and I need to logon to a webpage. For that I use HttpPost. This is what I am doing:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://202.163.117.123:8080/hitrack/default.aspx");
 try {
      // Add your data
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTTARGET", ""));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTARGUMENT", ""));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "user123"));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "pass456"));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ButtonLogin0", "Login"));
      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
      // Execute HTTP Post Request
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
      String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
      Log.d("response",responseBody);

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

But this shows me the source of same loginPage. Why does it not redirect to other page? Do I have to add a redirect handler. If yes, then do I to implement it?

I have tried, but that also didn't work.

Comment: This answer might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169468/handling-httpclient-redirects. Your problem might be that your client is not redirecting properly.

Comment: It might be that you aren't redirecting properly but you should also consider the form fields that you are passing. Depending on the way the ASP.NET backend is setup the viewstate and eventvalidation information being passed could potentially invalidate the login attempt as it throws an error trying to deserialize bad data. IMHO you should remove those fields entirely from your post.

Comment: thanks!removed..but it still results the same. if client is not redirecting properly, what should i consider to make my code work.

Comment: @RiNxX The consideration with regard to the redirect would be to handle the 302 header that *should* be returned from a valid login. Now if you are getting the source for the *entire* login page then something probably failed to authenticate -- I can't confirm that right now but I believe the authentication should just return a minimal data with a redirect header -- so there may be other things to consider. You might want to install some software that can help you inspect your network traffic so you can get a full picture of what is happening.