# Why do I get 302 HTTP status codes when I run my Scala test on Jenkins instead of 204?

Tags: http, scala, testing, jenkins, http-status-code-302

I have some tests of a REST API service that I've written in Scala. We're importing `org.apache.http` and using simple HTTP method such as:

```
val uri: HttpGet = new HttpGet(u)
val response: HttpResponse = http.execute(uri)
```

They go to URL such as:

`https://platform.company.com:443/ajax_request/login?username=me@company.com&password=pass`

or

`https://admin-platform.company.com:443/usergroups/rest/usergroups`

The tests are compiled with Maven and run on a Jenkins ver. 1.494 server.

The problem is that while the tests run flawlessly locally (when I do a `mvn clean test` on my laptop), they get unexpected status codes on the CI server. Locally I get 204, 200, 200, and 200 for these tests. But on CI I get 302, 302, 302, 200.

Do I need a special configuration option in Jenkins? Or a better authentication method?

I am able to successfully run cURL commands on the CI server itself, so I don't think it's a fundamental network connectivity issue, e.g.:

```
Running script  : #!/bin/bash

# get an auth session
curl -v -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -L "https://platform.company.com/ajax_request/login?
username=user&password=pass"

# get a list of company guids
curl -v -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -L
"https://platform.company.com/ajax_request/companies_selector"

# run this to make a call to service for company: 
curl -v -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt --cookie "company_guid=3f65b34d-b6f4-4abd-b14b-408b8a11059b"
-L "https://service-platform.company.com/users"
```

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Good point. Not sure why it's so low. Will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworker researched the problem. The tests were running perfect on another environment (we have several: qa, staging, production, demo, etc.). It looks as if the problem was the QA server had a self-signed SSL certificate which Jenkins was not accepting, or the client couldn't accept. I probably had manually accepted the cert on my local workstation, which is why the tests ran locally.

The fix would be for our IT department to use a real cert, as the other environment does.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear from your description, but it seems likely that the issue is a matter of 3xx redirections being followed automatically in some cases and not in others.

For example, when you use 'curl', you include the -L option so that 3xx redirections are followed automatically, which is what you want to happen.

Therefore, in your Java code, it is quite possible that your laptop is also following redirections, whereas you CI build server is not, due to it being unspecified.

Apache Http Client [should also](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html#d5e1225), by default, follow redirections.

If you'll forgive the plug, I have written an alternative HTTP client based on Java's *URLConnection* (called [**Bee Client**](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/bee-client) - please note that it's still at a beta release though).

Because *URLConnection* will follow redirections by default, that's also what Bee Client does.

```
val httpClient = new HttpClient
val response: Response = httpClient.get("https://admin-platform.company.com:443/usergroups/rest/usergroups")
```

The status code is included in the response and it will be a 2xx if there was no error.

There is an option to disable redirections, but it sounds like you don't need this.

Comment: Rick, thanks for the comments. I'm confused: if the client is supposed to follow redirects by default, why isn't it doing this on CI? I looked at the Apache documentation and it confirms what you're saying. So I'm not sure what to do next...

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer. We are doing an HttpPost in our login/authentication:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5170468/1759990

Comment: It's at best a really hack-like workaround that might have unintended consequences... so I'm hesitant to try it; and that's even if I could figure out how to code it.