# Possible redirect issue while trying to log in to website with HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient

I've copied ***Mkyong's Apache HttpClient*** example almost word for word except for swapping out the deprecated methods and my own log in information (I even managed to copy his typos!): [Mkyong's example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/)

```
private void sendPost(String url, List<NameValuePair> postParams) 
    throws Exception {

post.setParams(params);
post.setHeader("Host", "accounts.google.com");
post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
post.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
post.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
post.setHeader("Cookie", getCookies());
post.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
post.setHeader("Referer", "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth");
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}

System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

The print statement at the end of the method returns that the page has been 'moved temporarily'.

`<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE></HEAD><BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"><H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>The document has moved <A HREF="https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?chtml=LoginDoneHtml&amp;continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount&amp;gidl=CAA">here</A>.</BODY></HTML>`

I believe this is a redirect, though I am not entirely sure. Here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth";
String gmail = "https://mail.google.com/mail/";
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
HttpCilentExample http = new HttpCilentExample();
String page = http.GetPageContent(url);
List<NameValuePair> postParams = 
           http.getFormParams(page, "example@gmail.com","examplePassword"); 
http.sendPost(url, postParams);
System.out.println("past here");
String result = http.GetPageContent(gmail);
System.out.println(result);
}
```

The code does not process past `String result = http.GetPageContent(gmail);`

I believe that this has something to do with the issue (this is from [Handling HttpClient Redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169468/handling-httpclient-redirects))

> 10.3.3 302 Found ...
>
> If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other
>   than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
>   request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
>   change the conditions under which the request was issued.

I have attempted to override the `isRedirected()` method, but am unsure as to what I am supposed to do. Am I to return false for all cases, or check the parameters for ***POST*** cases?

I am unsure if this is the entire problem and am unsure if I am approaching this correctly at all.

However, I would appreciate any explanations that would help me understand the process of logging into a website using ***Httpclient***.

Comment: Before trying with code , you can test out your requirement with a http client postman http://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Where are you being redirected to?

Comment: @Taylor `https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?chtml=LoginDoneHtml&amp;continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount&amp;gidl=CAA`, though I am not sure if it is a redirect. I added the full return to the question

Comment: Check the response code.  If it's in the 300's it's a redirect.  That being said, based on the link, I'd guess the login is successful and google is trying to redirect your client to a page in order to push a cookie.  Note the continue param seems to want to push you to ManageAccount once CheckCookie is done.  What result are you expecting?

Comment: @Taylor From the sendPost() method, I get a 302. It does seem that the login is working. I think that if the cookies remain, I should be able to access the gmail page on 'mail.google.com/mail".