# Unable to receive data from HttpClient call

Tags: java, rest, resources

I'm trying to send a POST request through `HttpClient` to a Resource but it seems that there is no data to consume..

I've a filter before the call is passed to that resource to verify signature and validate it, but nothing happens after that.. no data is received at the resource end which triggers appropriate exception
here is my code to make the request

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
try {
CloseableHttpClient client=HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(API_BASE_URL + "/generateToken");
//Set Headers
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.addHeader("Signature",URLEncoder.encode(generateSignature(),"UTF-8"));
request.addHeader("Expires", String.valueOf(timestamp));
request.addHeader("AccessKey", URLEncoder.encode(accessKey, "UTF-8"));

//Add Paramets
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

//Sends Request
response = client.execute(request);

//Read From Response
BufferedReader reader;
InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
result.append(inputLine);
}
EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
```

I'm sending `login` and `pass` as List`<NameVaulePair>` parameters

My Resource code

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getToken(@FormParam("login") String slashtagOrEmail,
            @FormParam("pass") String password) {
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = publisherService.authenticate(slashtagOrEmail, password);
            return Response.ok().entity(token).build();
        } catch (RemoteException | EmailNotFoundException | UsernameNotFoundException | UnknownLoginException | IncorrectPasswordException | AccountNotConfirmedException ex) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(ex.toString()).build();
        }

    }
```

After I make the request I get `UsernameNotFoundException` which is basically for empty `slashtagOrEmail` variable

The JUnit Test for `publisherService.authenticate()` function gives proper result, I don't see where I'm making mistake(s).

*PS:This is my very first question on SO, please help me to frame questions better, Thanks Again*

Comment: What version of the Apache HttpClient are you using?

Comment: @sparks Httpclient-4.4 jar

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your code, you are using a ssl verifier and you might be connecting to http://example.com instead of https://example.com

In this case, its the **302** empty response. Because the server is redirecting port 80(default http port) requests to port 443 (default SSL port)

Check if the response code is **302**. HttpClient doesn't automatically redirect to the page. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5170468/1097600

```
System.out.println("Response Code : " 
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

#### Solution: Change url to https://example.com

Comment: `Https` isn't the issue `slashtagOrEmail` and `password` are both becomes `null` after the request is passed through `chain.dofilter()`