# Getting 500 error from HttpClient, works in browser

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, http-redirect

I'm using Apache HttpClient to try to submit some post data to a server. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the server to get any log information so that won't be possible.

If I go through this process with Firefox, it works fine. (I do get a 302 warning on this particular page)

I have matched the Request headers of both Firefox and my program.

Firefox Request Headers:

```
Host: server ip
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://server ip/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 407
Cookie: sessionId=blahblah
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

My Programs Request Headers shown from `context.getRequest().getAllHeaders();`

```
Host: server ip
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://server ip/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Length: 406
Cookie: sessionId=blahblah
```

I have matched the body of the request by comparing the output of `EntityUtils.toString(httpPost.getEntity(), "UTF-8");` and the built in tool for Firefox's tool to look at the request body, and they match almost character for character. (Just a slight difference in the session id which is expected as it's not using the same session.)

I'm not sure what else to check. What could be causing the server to behave differently between the Browser and the program?

Below is my code for the POST request.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://" + getIp() + "");

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FTPUsername", "blah"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FTPPassword", "blah"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FormButtonSubmit", "OK"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

httpPost.setHeader("Host", ip);
httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0");
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"); 
httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5"); 
httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"); 
httpPost.setHeader("Referer", referer);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpPost.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
httpPost.setHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");

//Response
HttpResponse response = getHttpClient().execute(httpPost, LoginRequest.context);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
httpPost.releaseConnection();
```

I realize this could probably be many things since 500 is a server error, but it's got to be something I'm submitting wrong or I'm missing something as it works perfectly in the browser.

Comment: @Justas GET request with a request body? I don't think that would work.

Comment: @Austin since it seems to have a server side session, maybe there's something in that session put in the previous requests with firefox that allows it to work. You could try a headless browser such as htmlunit, phantomjs or similar.

Comment: Though this might be just way out of the picture, but could you let me know why is the `Content-Length: 406` one less than the firefox's `Content-Length: 407` headers...Is there a character that you've missed in your request?

Comment: the firefox versions are different, if that matters

Comment: @nullpointer It's the session id that is random, so when it gets encoded sometimes it's longer/shorter due to special characters.

Comment: @Igor I tried updating the version in my headers and still the 500 error. Thanks

Comment: @Austin There must be some error logs as well with a 500, can you share the server logs for it in that case.

Comment: @nullpointer unfortunately I can't access the server to get the logs.

Comment: Possible for you to attach a HAR when you do it in browser? Also it should be from a incognito browser.

Comment: Can you at lest share the Error 500 response with headers?

Comment: https : perhaps it's a self signed cert which was accepted once in FF but has to be trusted by the java client ?

Comment: can you run any other form submit with HttpClient to different url?

Comment: can you list the reponse headers?

Comment: Can you try using POSTMAN to post data on the server

Answer (score 7):

302 "warning" is actually a redirect. HTTP Client does do redirect automatically, you must flag the `RedirectStrategy`, For HttpClient 4.3:

```
HttpClient instance = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                     .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
```

see [examples in answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169468/handling-httpclient-redirects) and [w3 docs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than
>   GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
>   request unless it can be confirmed by the user

Answer (score 0):

Do you work with Windows machine? or Linux machine?

If you use a windows machine, have you tried working with WAMP server for Linux use LAMP server, so if you install it, you won't get those errors, that's how I fixed my error. Once if you install these two servers, change the port number in skype by logging into Skype and change the port number or uninstall your skype. It should work.