# Geting exception while trying to call a service over http

Tags: java, http, https

I am registering only http scheme for java httpclient 4.1.3

```
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", host.getPort(), PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
```

When trying to do call to some http://blabla.bla I am getting the exception below:

```
...
Caused by: org.apache.http.HttpException: Scheme 'https' not registered.
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultHttpRoutePlanner.java:109)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:762)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
    ... 8 more
```

I believe it's related with environment/endpoint, as it does not work in this particular case only.

I will appreciate any help for this.

Comment: Your client got a redirect to a more secure (https) url. It seems the server provide http services too but only for redirecting the clients. You should check your link from a browser at active debugging window and preserved/keeped network log, if you see 301 or 302, you can see the (better) URL in that request.

Comment: Very thanks, could you provide any real URL that works in the same way?
BTW curl posting successfully.

Comment: curl does not follow the redirects by default (except you give -L), so it should have another reason

Comment: Are you sure that your URL starts with HTTP? Could you share the related part of your client's code?

Comment: @m4gic Is redirection turned off in Postman and ARC tool as well?

Comment: Don't know, please check it in the documentation or use a proxy (like TCPTunnelGUI) or a network profiler to check it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I see Java HttpClient is also does not redirect automatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169468/handling-httpclient-redirects

Comment: Maybe it would be enough just register a https socket factory: schemeRegistry.register(
    new Scheme("https", 443, SSLSocketFactory.getSystemSocketFactory())
);