# Enable Javascript HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using HttpClient and today I get the following message:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="CacheControl" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo="/>
    <script>

(function(){
    var securemsg;
    var dosl7_common;

window["bobcmn"] = "111110111010102000000022000000052000000002633c6615200000096300000000300000000300000006/TSPD/300000008TSPD_101300000005https200000000200000000";

window.bLk=!!window.bLk;try{(function(){try{var OO,zO,sO=1,jO=1,JO=1,LO=1,oO=1,_z=1,iz=1,Jz=1,Lz=1;for(var oz=0;oz<zO;++oz)sO+=2,jO+=2,JO+=2,LO+=2,oO+=2,_z+=2,iz+=2,Jz+=2,Lz+=3;OO=sO+jO+JO+LO+oO+_z+iz+Jz+Lz;window.ZI===OO&&(window.ZI=++OO)}catch(_Z){window.ZI=OO}var lZ=!0;function oZ(O){O&&(lZ=!1,document.cookie="brav=ad");return lZ}function Os(){}oZ(window[Os.name]===Os);oZ("function"!==typeof ie9rgb4);oZ(/\x3c/.test(function(){return"\x3c"})&!/x3d/.test(function(){return"'x3'+'d';"}));
var zs=window.attachEvent||/mobi/i.test(window["\x6e\x61vi\x67a\x74\x6f\x72"]["\x75\x73e\x72A\x67\x65\x6et"]),ss=+new Date+6E5,Ss,_s,Is=setTimeout,Js=zs?3E4:6E3;function ls(){if(!document.querySelector)return!0;var O=+new Date,s=O>ss;if(s)return oZ(!1);s=_s&&Ss+Js<O;s=oZ(s);Ss=O;_s||(_s=!0,Is(function(){_s=!1},1));return s}ls();var Ls=[17795081,27611931586,1558153217];
function os(O){O="string"===typeof O?O:O.toString(36);var s=window[O];if(!s.toString)return;var _=""+s;window[O]=function(O,_){_s=!1;return s(O,_)};window[O].toString=function(){return _}}for(var Lz=0;Lz<Ls.length;++Lz)os(Ls[Lz]);oZ(!1!==window.bLk);(function(){var O={decrypt:function(O){try{return JSON.parse(function(O){O=O.split("l");var s="";for(var _=0;_<O.length;++_)s+=String.fromCharCode(O[_]);return s}(O))}catch(_){}}};return O={configuration:O.decrypt("123l34l97l99l116l105l118l101l34l58l34l110l111l34l44l34l100l101l98l117l103l103l105l110l103l34l58l34l110l111l34l44l34l109l111l100l117l108l101l49l34l58l34l101l110l97l98l108l101l100l34l44l34l109l111l100l117l108l101l50l34l58l34l101l110l97l98l108l101l100l34l44l34l109l111l100l117l108l101l51l34l58l34l101l110l97l98l108l101l100l34l44l34l109l111l100l117l108l101l52l34l58l34l101l110l97l98l108l101l100l34l125")}})();
var zS=90;window.jl={Ll:"08e07175890178004c7047e0b7b2c9820d9bce8ea52f6db3f5553780217a685ee156050cbec5e21db17d02cc9f2f04977a04f19db8a7bd4c36d82f74e4ea6526ef9f37915fdb607c258691cf631babe21bbf0fe58449639b86ad73a49ef84f6b376a19faa6643e19e31f6bc700a660c5a275ccec64a4d91916762d95b2676cf0"};function z(O){return 352>O}function Z(O){var s=arguments.length,_=[];for(var J=1;J<s;++J)_.push(arguments[J]-O);return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,_)}function S(O,s){O+=s;return O.toString(36)}(function ZS(s){s&&"number"!==typeof s||("number"!==typeof s&&(s=1E3),s=Math.max(s,1),setInterval(function(){ZS(s-10)},s))})(ls());})();}catch(x){document.cookie='brav=oex'+x;}finally{ie9rgb4=void(0);};function ie9rgb4(a,b){return a>>b>>0};

})();

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/TSPD/0830948a12ab200004d69498ba5037bf6a058a7a372b?type=8">
    </script>
    <script>    

(function(){
    var securemsg;
    var dosl7_common;

window["blobfp"] = "1111111110112000003e826ab81512300000000300000020http://re.security.f5aas.com/re/";


})();

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/TSPD/0830948a12ab200004d69498b?type=11">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.
    </noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

This implementation was functional until yesterday:

```
HttpResponse response;
HttpPost httpPost;
HttpEntity entity;
List < NameValuePair > parametros = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ( );
String URL = "";
String mensaje;
try {
    httpPost = new HttpPost ( URL );
    parametros.add ( new BasicNameValuePair ( "submit", "MODIFICAR" ) );
    httpPost.setEntity ( new UrlEncodedFormEntity ( parametros, Consts.UTF_8 ) );
    response = httpClient.execute ( httpPost );
    entity = response.getEntity ( );
    mensaje = EntityUtils.toString ( entity );
    EntityUtils.consume ( entity );
    Document document = Jsoup.parse ( mensaje );
    System.out.println ( document.toString ( ) );
} catch ( IOException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace ( );
}
```

There is some way in which you can solve this `response`
I have read that it is an implementation of f5 networks, there is an alternative for this problem, I have implmentado the query with htmlUnit enabling javascript, but the error persists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling HttpClient Redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169468/handling-httpclient-redirects)

Comment: @spi status code `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

Comment: 200 OK + "Object moved" in body? You will have to discover manually where is the new page, because you should have got a 301 Moved + Location header to indicate where is the now location. This site seems not to follow common practices.