# Unable to take page screenshot

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to take a screenshot of page https://przegladarka-ekw.ms.gov.pl/eukw_prz/KsiegiWieczyste/wyszukiwanieKW but I only receive message that my request was rejected.

I'm using code as below

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');         // Require Puppeteer module 
const url = "https://przegladarka-ekw.ms.gov.pl/eukw_prz/KsiegiWieczyste/wyszukiwanieKW";           // Set website you want to screenshot
const Screenshot = async () => {                // Define Screenshot function
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, slowMo: 250});    // Launch a "browser"
   const page = await browser.newPage();        // Open a new page
   await page.goto(url);                        // Go to the website

   await page.screenshot({                      // Screenshot the website using defined options
    path: "./screenshot.png",                   // Save the screenshot in current directory
    fullPage: true                              // take a fullpage screenshot
  });
  await page.close();                           // Close the website
  await browser.close();                        // Close the browser
}
Screenshot();                                   // Call the Screenshot function
```

In normal browser page is blank and after seconds refresh and then display normally so I'm trying to was for all redirections but it doesn't work

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');         // Require Puppeteer module 
const url = "https://przegladarka-ekw.ms.gov.pl/eukw_prz/KsiegiWieczyste/wyszukiwanieKW";           // Set website you want to screenshot
const Screenshot = async () => {                // Define Screenshot function
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, slowMo: 250});    // Launch a "browser"
   const page = await browser.newPage();        // Open a new page
   await page.goto(url);                        // Go to the website

   page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text()));
   await page.evaluate(() => console.log(`url is ${location.href}`));

   
    await page.waitForSelector('#numerKsiegiWieczystej', { visible: true, timeout: 0 });
   await page.screenshot({                      // Screenshot the website using defined options
    path: "./screenshot.png",                   // Save the screenshot in current directory
    fullPage: true                              // take a fullpage screenshot
  });
  await page.close();                           // Close the website
  await browser.close();                        // Close the browser
}
Screenshot();                                   // Call the Screenshot function
```

Comment: Possibly related, due to `bobcmn`: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54538792/enable-javascript-httpclient), [2](https://github.com/cmalita/api-mfinante), [3](https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/issues/2265)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page has a bot detection script `window["bobcmn"]` so add these to your package.json :

```js
"puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.6",
"puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.2",
```

then the code to take a screenshot will be :

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

let browser;
(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
const page = await browser.newPage();
let url = 'https://przegladarka-ekw.ms.gov.pl/eukw_prz/KsiegiWieczyste/wyszukiwanieKW';

async function screenshot(url) {

    await page.goto(url,{ waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout:60000});
    await page.waitForSelector('div.content');
    await page.screenshot({path : "./screenshot.png", fullPage: true});

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
}

await screenshot(url);

})().catch(err => console.error(err)).finally(() => browser ?. close());
```