# http:outbound-gateway to follow redirect

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I need to request a JWT Token via an HTTP request in my Spring Integration application.

I've configured a plain http outbound gatway but the server replies with a 301 Moved Permanently;

It requires the client to follow a redirect (and apparently it works this way doing some tests with SOAP-UI);

How could I make the http-outbound-gateway to follow redirects?

Tried everything I could find, but nothing worked so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need consider to configure your HTTP Outbound Gateway with a `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`. This one is based on the Apache HTTP Client 4.x and its default behavior is a `DefaultRedirectStrategy` which does a redirect on `GET` and `HEAD` methods and when `302`, `301` or `307` status is returned for the call.

If you need to redirect `POST`, consider to configure an underlying `HttpClient` with a `LaxRedirectStrategy`.

See more info here: [Handling HttpClient Redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169468/handling-httpclient-redirects)

**UPDATE**

To configure a `LaxRedirectStrategy` for the `HttpClient` used in the `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` you need something like this:

```
<beans:bean id="httpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients" factory-method="custom">
    <beans:property name="redirectStrategy" value="#{new org.apache.http.impl.client.LaxRedirectStrategy()}"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="clientHttpRequestFactory"
      class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean factory-bean="httpClientBuilder" factory-method="build"/>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

It is kinda pitta to do all that stuff in XML, so consider to move your project to Java & annotation configuration.

Comment: Thanks Artem, It worked perfectly! Unfortunately the service I'm trying to use has further issues, but that's not SI fault :)